# Python Regex replacement with sequential replacements from list of value

Tags: python, string, replace

I have a big problem with this regex.

I have a string, which can contain multiple and differents links anywhere inside. I need to take those links and make a list of them, then i elaborate them with an url shortener. Then have to replace them sequentially in the string with the new link i have.
For the first part i've done this:

```
links = []
links_in_message = re.findall(r'(https?:\/\/(?:www\.|(?!www))[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[^\s]{2,}|www\.[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[^\s]{2,}|https?:\/\/(?:www\.|(?!www))[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[^\s]{2,}|www\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[^\s]{2,})', message.text)
if links_in_message:
    links.extend(links_in_message)
```

And for example this string:

```
string = 'Hello www.fb.com/home how are you https://twitter.it/home ?'
```

should become (where the link are not a substitution of the domain with rere.me, but every link is taken sequentially from my links list):

```
//Result = 'Hello www.rere.me/home how are you https://rere.me/home ?'
```

I'm thinking about deleting the links from the string and help me saving link index in string to compose a new string but i was wondering if there was another way. Thank you.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're trying to substitute the links you've found with. Do you have another list of links, e.g. `substitution_links`?

Comment: In the first code in the question i compose a list of link that are the string, then i send them to an url shortener which give me another link for everyone. i have to replace them sequentially in the string with the new link i have

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `string.replace` since you have the exact text (links) that you want to replace.

For example:

```
for link in links:
   string = string.replace(link, shorten_link(link), 1)
```

Comment: those little things you should thing first...

Comment: Sorry? Not sure what you're saying.

Comment: That it makes so sense that i'm asking how i can't even think about your solution :P

Comment: i have an error actually: message= message.replace(link, links(link), 1)
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

Comment: I just used `shorten_link(link)` as an example. You'd have to replace it with your shortened link.